# Is there an R implementation for Java or .NET?

Tags: java, .net, r

Is there Java or .NET version of R?
(like Jython / IronPython for the Python language)

I guess some R-packages which use C or Fortran may not run on Java/.NET version of R, but as long as pure R code can be run, it must be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Renjin is a pure-JVM implementation of the R language.
It's very much under development and not production ready, but making good progress.

http://code.google.com/p/renjin

Comment: Does REngine support 'imputeTS' package in R?

Answer (score 15):

A pure Java implementation of R: https://www.renjin.org/

[**JRI**](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) allows you to call R from any Java program, so any language on the JVM should be able to call the JRI jars.  See my example of how to use this in this question: [R from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180235/r-from-within-java).  As an example, there is a clojure library that is currently being developed around JRI by [Joel Boehland](http://joelboehland.com/): [**Rincanter**](http://github.com/jolby/rincanter) ([read about it here](http://data-sorcery.org/category/rincanter/)).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this is technically no longer correct.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim.  I had seen renjin a while ago, but forgot about this question.  :)

Answer (score 5):

If you needs stats on the pure JVM, you might try Incanter (www.incanter.org).  It's an R-like library for Clojure, which brings lispy functional programming to the JVM.  It looks like a really cool start-up with some potential.  They have a pretty active user community already on their google group.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 that I know of.

http://www.renjin.org/ - Renjin

https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin - Renjin

and...

https://github.com/allr/purdue-fastr - FastR

https://bitbucket.org/allr/fastr - FastR

Answer (score 1):

[FastR](https://github.com/oracle/fastr) is a [GraalVM](http://www.graalvm.org/) based implementation of R. It runs on any JVM, but with GraalVM you get extra performance with the Graal compiler and Truffle framework.

On top of running existing R scripts, it has some additional features w.r.t. embeddability in JVM applications and interoperability with JVM and other GraalVM languages (including JavaScript, Ruby, Python 3).

More details in https://medium.com/graalvm/faster-r-with-fastr-4b8db0e0dceb