# Using R in Processing through rJava/JRI?

Tags: java, r, processing

Is it possible to run R in Processing through rJava/JRI? If I deployed a Processing app on the web, would the client need R on their system?

I'm looking to create an interactive information dashboard that I can deploy on the web. It seems that Processing is probably my best bet for the interactive/web part of things. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there are many math/stats functions built-in. And there aren't any libraries for plotting data either.

I've been using R and gpplot2 for a few months and am thrilled (amazed) at how easily it manipulates and plots data.

So I'm wondering now if can get the best of both worlds and run R through a Processing applet.

From the [JRI](http://rosuda.org/JRI/) website:

> JRI is a Java/R Interface, which allows to run R inside Java
>   applications as a single thread.
>   Basically it loads R dynamic library
>   into Java and provides a Java API to R
>   functionality. It supports both simple
>   calls to R functions and a full
>   running REPL.
>
> In a sense JRI is the inverse of rJava
>   and both can be combined (i.e. you can
>   run R code inside JRI that calls back
>   to the JVM via rJava). The JGR project
>   makes the full use of both JRI and
>   rJava to provide a full Java GUI for
>   R.
>
> JRI uses native code, but it supports
>   all platforms where Sun's Java (or
>   compatible) is available, including
>   Windows, Mac OS X, Sun and Linux (both
>   32-bit and 64-bit).

Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you write Java code (or access a Jar file) in Processing?  If so, then you can absolutely do this.  JRI provides a low level interface to R and I have yet to encounter something in R that couldn't be run through its functions.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180235/r-from-within-java) for simple example of how to use it.

I haven't really used Processing other than to look at it a few times, but it was my understanding that it had its own language.

Comment: It has it's own SYNTAX, but it's Java, under the hood. It compiles to and runs on the JVM, packages in JAR, etc. It's edge is providing convenience functions for a lot of graphics operations, so you don't have to deal directly with Swing or any other Java2D or Java3D prims.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some example code along these lines last year:

http://illposed.net/R4P.html

Best,

Bryan

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the [Incanter](http://data-sorcery.org/about/) library for Clojure. It's an R-like library in Clojure, pretty fast due to the (pure java) Parallel Colt numerics library, with built-in JFreeChart support for quick charting as well as a wrapper for using Processing through Clojure.

You could just push the resulting app to the web as a normal (though probably pretty big) Java Applet.