# Matrix multiplication in java

Tags: java, r, matrix-multiplication

I wanted to do matrix multiplication in Java, and the speed needs to be very good.

I was thinking of calling R through java to achieve this.

I had a couple of Qs though:

1. Is calling R using Java a good idea? If yes, are there any code samples that can be shared?
2. What are the other ways that can be considered to do matrix multiplication in Java?

#### Update:

My colleague who quit the firm was a C# programmer, who was forced to write Java code that involved matrix multiplication.

-- He has written his own DataTable class in Java, in order to be able to

a) create indexes to sort and join with other DataTables

b) matrix multiplication.

So, I want to essentially clean up the code, and thought using something like R within Java will help me focus on business logic rather than sorting, joining, matrix multiplication, etc.

Comment: Heaving large amounts of data in and out of a JVM can be rather resource consuming.  Profile first to see if the pure-Java results are fast enough.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. For almost any math question of the form "I want to do X in Y", there's always an optimized package out there. Search for "lapack java" or "blas java" or even "matrix multiplication java".

Answer (score 4):

You could use a matrix package such as [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).

Answer (score 4):

There are several stackoverflow questions on using R with Java. This is simple with **[JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/)**. See this question for an example: [R from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180235/r-from-within-java).  Once you have integrated your code, doing the matrix multiplication in R is trivial.  If you have two matrices, `a` and `b`, you would simply call: `a %*% b`.

If you want to stay in pure Java and work with a mathematics library, you can also look into using [**Colt**](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) (which is adapted from [JAMA](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/linalg/package-summary.html#Overview)), although you could be better off just [using **JAMA** directly](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).

Another option would be to use [**Incanter** from Clojure](http://incanter.org/) (which provides a wrapper around [Parallel Colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt), amongst other things), and then call it as a Jar from Java.  It's trivial to integrate Clojure into Java, and if all you want is matrix multiplication, that will be easier for you than using R.

Answer (score 0):

[EJML](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/)  seems to be a promising new one for fast multiplication.  They have benchmarks on their site to show what they claim to be fast times for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

[Parallel colt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parallelcolt/) is an effective library to perform matrix operations .

Other good matrix libraries would include [jblas](http://jblas.org/) and [ujmp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ujmp/)

All of these packages are effective. jblas is my personal favourite . It has good documentation and straight forward unlike ujmp

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for `jblas`. all the methods are like you'd expect them to be.