# Calling rscript from Java

Tags: java, r

We are trying to build analytic platform where we wish to use R. We have some sensor observation Service where we are getting some sensor specific values in xml format(OGC standard Sensor Observation Service) with large volume.These part have been implemented in JAVA and working fine. Now we need to give a hook to application developer who can pass Rscript written for these data,input data and output format and pass to R like API or function call. Also would like to get return data from R. What could be the effective way so that it would be easy for application developer and in terms of performance? We have seen Rserve but couldn't find the way to pass Rscipt(block of R commands). Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the interface rJava as mentioned in this thread: [R from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2180235/1183242). You will find a short usage example there too.